# Parse JSON data from string

Tags: json, http, arduino

I'm getting JSON data using HTTP methods in Arduino and storing in a String object. The data is:

```
{
  "item": {
    "Identity": {
      "Id": "327681",
      "ItemId": "64006A962B71A1E7B3A0428637DA997C.327681",
      "Level": 1,
      "EntityType": "64006A962B71A1E7B3A0428637DA997C",
      "ItemStatus": 1
    },
    "Properties": {
      "AssetName": "PHE-1001",
      "Category": "Electrical Appliance",
      "RegistrationTime": "2017-12-14Z",
      "Activated": true,
      "Status": "Offline",
      "Manufacturer": "Philips",
      "ModelNumber": "1E-S00ER11",
      "SerialNumber": "YGTJGJK458545",
      "sample_property": null,
      "AssetLocation": null,
      "AssetType": null,
      "ActivationTime": "2017-12-24T05:44:38Z",
      "Country": "India",
      "PostalAddress": "500081",
      "dummy": null,
      "TotalHours": 16,
      "TotalWorkingHoursFromInstallation": 38,
      "TotalLifeTime": 62,
      "AssetSensorDistance": null
    }
  }
}
```

Arduino code:

```
HTTPClient http;
http.begin("URL");
int httpCode = http.GET(); //  //Send the request
if (httpCode == 200) {
  String payload = http.getString();
  Serial.println(payload);
}
```

Now I want to get only `AssetName`, `Status` and `AssetSensorDistance`. I have tried `payload["Status"]` but it prints nothing.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some important bits here.

- You need to include the ArduinoJson library
- You need to actually parse the string into a JsonObject using JsonBuffer
- The path to status would be yourRootObject["Properties"]["Status"], since it is contained inside your Properties.

See here:  https://arduinojson.org/doc/decoding/

Good Luck!

Comment: StaticJsonBuffer<200> jsonBuffer;
      JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(payload);
      if (!root.success())
      {
          Serial.println("Parsing Failed");
      }

it is printing "Parsing failed"

Comment: Your input buffer is too small, you need at least 842 bytes.  See this,  http://arduinojson.org/faq/why-parsing-fails/ and also this really cool tool: http://arduinojson.org/assistant/ . Btw got that by googling "ArduinoJson parsing failed"... Google is your friend :-)